# AnalysisException: Failure when resolving conflicting references in Join: 'Join Inner

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have this simple code

```
var count = event_stream
      .groupBy("value").count()

event_stream.join(count,"value").printSchema() //get error on this line
```

event_stream and count schemas are as follows

```
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

root
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

two questions

Why do I get this error and how to fix?

Why does groupby.count drops all other columns?

The error is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Failure when resolving conflicting references in Join:
'Join Inner
:- AnalysisBarrier
:     +- StreamingRelationV2 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@7f2c57fe, kafka, Map(startingOffsets -> latest, failOnDataLoss -> false, subscribe -> events-identification-carrier, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> svc-kafka-pre-c1-01.jamba.net:9092), [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@3dbd7107,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(startingOffsets -> latest, failOnDataLoss -> false, subscribe -> events-identification-carrier, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> svc-kafka-pre-c1-01.jamba.net:9092),None), kafka, [key#0, value#1, topic#2, partition#3, offset#4L, timestamp#5, timestampType#6]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Aggregate [value#8], [value#8, count(1) AS count#46L]
         +- StreamingRelationV2 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@7f2c57fe, kafka, Map(startingOffsets -> latest, failOnDataLoss -> false, subscribe -> events-identification-carrier, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> svc-kafka-pre-c1-01.jamba.net:9092), [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@3dbd7107,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(startingOffsets -> latest, failOnDataLoss -> false, subscribe -> events-identification-carrier, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> svc-kafka-pre-c1-01.jamba.net:9092),None), kafka, [key#0, value#1, topic#2, partition#3, offset#4L, timestamp#5, timestampType#6]

Conflicting attributes: value#8
```

**EDIT: yes!** the changing the name of the columns works. 
But now, If I use the join, I have to use **OutputMode.Append** and for that, I need to add **Watermarks** to the stream.

What I want is extract the count and topic(from the above printed schema) in the resultingDF and write that to some Sink.

Two questions

1. Is there any other way/better way to do this?
2. Can I do multiple aggs like count() and then also add another column which is of String type i.e. topic is this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why do I get this error and how to fix?**

I think you are getting the error because the final joined schema contains two value fields, one from each side of the join.  To fix this rename the "value" field on one of the two joined Streams like this:

```
var count = event_stream.
    groupBy("value").count().
    withColumnRenamed("value", "join_id")

event_stream.join(count, $"value" === $"join_id").
    drop("join_id").  
    printSchema()
```

**Why does groupby.count drops all other columns?**

`groupBy` operations basically are dividing your fields up into two lists.  A list of fields to use as the key, and a list of fields to aggregate.  The key fields just show up as is in the final result, but any fields not in the list need to have an aggregate operation defined to show up in the result.  Otherwise spark has no way to know how you want to combine multiple values of that field!  Did you want to just count it?  Did you want the max value?  Did you want to see all distinct values?  To specify how to rollup a field, you can define it in a .agg(..) call.

Example:

```
val input = Seq(
    (1, "Bob", 4),
    (1, "John", 5)
).toDF("key", "name", "number")

input.groupBy("key").
    agg(collect_set("name") as "names",
        max("number") as "maxnum").
    show

+---+-----------+------+
|key|name       |maxnum|
+---+-----------+------+
|  1|[Bob, John]|     5|
+---+-----------+------+
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for error is the column name which is used for joining .
You can use the operation like .

```
var count = event_stream
      .groupBy("value").count()

event_stream.join(count,Seq("value"))
```

Comment: its the same thing what i have written. Tried it before posting. doesnt works